# script to check entire website to figure out if there are any pages which are taking more time to load

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Can we have a script which will crawl through the entire website to figure out if there are any pages which are taking more time to load (some pages under a particular category were taking more time to load)  in selenium Webdriver or jmeter

Answer (score 0):

For JMeter you can use [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) configuration element for this purposes. From the documentation:

> **Spidering Example**
>
> Consider a simple example: let's say you wanted JMeter to "spider" through your site, hitting link after link parsed from the HTML returned from your server (this is not actually the most useful thing to do, but it serves as a good example). You would create a [Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller), and add the "HTML Link Parser" to it. Then, create an HTTP Request, and set the domain to ".*", and the path likewise. This will cause your test sample to match with any link found on the returned pages. If you wanted to restrict the spidering to a particular domain, then change the domain value to the one you want. Then, only links to that domain will be followed.

More information on above approach and a couple more options: [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial)

Remember that JMeter is not a browser hence it doesn't execute JavaScript so your results may not be precise enough as JMeter doesn't measure the time required to actually render the page.